# Understanding bit-level float multiplication in C?

Tags: c, floating-point, bit-manipulation, bit

I tried to implement `float_twice(float_bits x)` in C, which multiplies `x` by 2 in bit-level.
I compared the result of float_twice and the real float multiplication implemented in C, but found a difference.

`float_twice(0X800001)` yields `0X1000001`, and this seems correct to me. As long as I understand, `0X80001` is a floating point representation of exponent `1`, and fractional part `1`. Since it is a normalized value, I believe adding one to the exponent part is sufficient.

However, `((float) 0X800001) * 2.0` yields `0X1000002`.

This seems to be a multiplication of unsigned integers, not float values.

To summarize, these are my questions,

1. What is the correct output for `float_twice(0X800001)`?
2. If the correct output is `0X1000001`, why does C compute `((float) 0X800001) * 2.0` as `0X1000002`?

Comment: `(float) 0X800001` means to convert the integer `0x800001` to the floating point number with the closest numeric value, it doesn't interpret the bit pattern as a floating point number.

Comment: E.g. `(float) 1 == 1.0`

Comment: You might want to look at [this code](https://github.com/carlosgaldino/cs-app/blob/master/ch02/float_half.c), which halves a floating-point number rather than doubling it. But be aware that (i) the code is very non-portable; (ii) it doesn't cover any special cases like NANs; and (iii) it handles denormalised numbers, but not overflows (which of course never occur when you halve a number).

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I understand the problem in my code. I should use something like reinterpret_cast, right?

Comment: @Kang There is no such thing as `reinterperet_cast` in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test is incorrect: `((float) 0X800001)` converts the integer value `0x800001` to the closest `float` value, not to a `float` with the same bit representation.

To check your results, you must perform type punning, which can be done portably with `memcpy`:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef uint32_t float_bits;

float_bits check_twice(float_bits x) {
    float f;
    float_bits r;
    memcpy(&f, &x, sizeof f);
    f *= 2;
    memcpy(&r, &f, sizeof r);
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Aha! You caught on to the `memcpy` thing that I've been spreading around.

Comment: @JL2210: I'm sorry to admit it. `f = *(float *)&x` is much more explicit... but cannot be used because of the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: @chqrlie: Cannot be used because it's not defined. There's no "strict aliasing rule" that says you can't do this. It's just never been a defined behavior.

Comment: R.: *It's just never been a defined behavior* is quite a bold statement! The strict aliasing rules makes it undefined since Ansi C in 1990, to allow for better optimisations, which sometimes seem counter-intuitive. Too bad Dennis R. cannot tell us if he intended for `f = *(float *)&x` to behave as expected in the early days of the C language... His *C Reference Manual* from the seventies, before the cast syntax was invented, shows much worse type punning approaches: https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/cman.pdf pp23,24